# Android - GitHub Open Source Project android-alt-installer

Tags: android

I have some questions regarding the Github open source project...from this link https://github.com/android-enhancement/android-alt-installer as it creates custom installer.

Is it specific to device's android operating system or an application..? so that i will be able modify installer code for my application, so that it runs the same install procedure on all android devices.

I would like to modify installer as to perform some check for a file before installing the app.If the file is not present the installation should be aborted.

I have a Windows 7 OS and developing apps using eclipse IDE.

Also I read the README.txt in the above link (repeatedly) and I was not able to understand.

Can I implement the custom installer to my application..?, could one any give me a simple and clear explanation.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: That seems to require a custom rom.

Comment: @user1615903 so it is specific to each android device...so that we have to change the Operating systems installer class by rooting it.?Sorry if i am wrong... as i am new to android programming....